# Prophet Predict Method Understanding

Tags: machine-learning, facebook-prophet

I have been using FB Prophet in one of my projects and I have been trying to understand what predict method is doing.

```
m = Prophet()

m.fit(df)

future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)

forecast = m.predict(future)
```

When I check forecast it also predicts for historical data as well.
For me, I'm not sure why this is needed.

What I can think of is you can now compare your training data with this forecast data and calculate RMSE between them to understand how it is performing.

Any thoughts or ideas?